# change value of 2 fields depending on dropdown and radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, onchange

I am trying to replicate the sort of functionality which is present on [this website](http://www.squaretrade.com/tv-warranty). The price, mentioned above the 'Get a Protective Plan' button, updates with respect to different options selected from the dropdown and the radio button selected.

Now I have a form which has 2 read-only input field's for 'Price' and 'Price-2' and I want the value of those fields to be updated depending on the selection of the dropdown options and the radio button by the user. So basically, the values of the read-only input fields, which needs to be updated, will be an addition of the values of the selected dropdown option and the radio button.

Here's a rough example of the form which I've created along with the dropdown and the radio buttons:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

      <label>Last Name*</label>

        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" required="true">

                <select id="p1">
                        <option value="1">$1</option>
                        <option value="2">$2</option>
                        <option value="3">$3</option>
                        <option value="4">$4</option>
                        <option value="5">$5</option>
                </select>

                <input id="p2" type="radio" name="price2" value="50">$50<br/>
                <input id="p2" type="radio" name="price2" value="100">$100

      <label>Price</label>

        <input type="text" name="Price" readonly="readonly" value="">

            <input type="text" name="Price-2" readonly="readonly" value="">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So in this form if I select the second option from the dropdown whose value is '2' and then I select the first radio button whose value is '50', I'd want the value of the 'Price' and the 'Price-2' fields to automatically become '$52'. I know this can be achieved using jQuery but I cannot really figure out how as I am still learning it. Looking forward to get a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can accomplish using `JQuery`,

Here is a Fiddle [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/BmR8d) for your desired result.